# Does PowerShell's Exchange Online module provide for any auth. other than Basic?

Tags: azure, active-directory, exchange-server

At work our Group Policy blocks WinRM from using Basic authentication. As a result any machine used to remotely connect to one of our Exchange Online servers has to be moved to an OU which doesn't contain this GP and then moved back afterwards.

I have implemented the MFA EO module in order to mitigate some security issues, and that was deemed satisfactory for a time, but now I am being asked to remove all Basic auth. and this is one of the last places I can't seem to find any solution.

I know Azure allows OAuth with AD. I have run a few demos and successfully authenticate and get a token, but I can't seem to get it working in Exchange Online.

Is there any way to use OAuth with PowerShell's Exchange Online Module?